# Multi variable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = 1 $ for all $x+y \ge 2$ &

$f(x,y)=-1$ for all $x+y \lt 2$

Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

I have just started studying this topic. Please provide hints.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct question?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the limits along the line $x=y=t$, $t\in\Bbb{R}$ when $t\to 1^-$ and $t\to 1^+$. Are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

What is the value of $f(1,1)$ ?

Then consider, $x_n=1$ and $y_n=1-\frac 1 n$ and compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n,y_n)$.

What can you conclude ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $l\in\mathbb R$. I will prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}f(x,y)\neq(1,1)$. That is, I will prove that there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that$$(\forall\delta>0)\bigl(\exists(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\bigr):d\bigl((x,y),(1,1)\bigr)<\delta\wedge\bigl|f(x,y)-l\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon.$$For that, I take $\varepsilon=1$. If $l\geqslant0$, choose a $(x,y)$ such $x+y<2$ and such that $d\bigl((x,y),(1,1)\bigr)<\delta$; otherwise, choose a $(x,y)$ such $x+y\geqslant2$ and such that $d\bigl((x,y),(1,1)\bigr)<\delta$. In both cases, $\bigl|f(x,y)-l\bigr|\geqslant1$.